# Why are redirects in servlets required to be absolute?

Tags: java, url, servlets, redirect, absolute

Can anyone tell me WHY redirects in servlets are required to be absolute? All references I found just tell me they need to be absolute.

From the spec:

> The `sendRedirect` method will set the appropriate headers and content
>   body to redirect the client to a different `URL`. It is legal to call
>   this method with a relative `URL` path, however the underlying container
>   must translate the relative path to a fully qualified `URL` for
>   transmission back to the client. If a partial `URL` is given and, for
>   whatever reason, cannot be converted into a valid `URL`, then this
>   method must throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 2):

[Section 14.30 of RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) (HTTP/1.1, since superseded) mandated absolute URLs in the `Location` header used to indicate the "where" of a redirect. This has been relaxed in more recent versions of the spec, but the Servlet specification still requires the backwards-compatible behavior.

Comment: Do you also know why HTTP enforced this (security?)

Comment: @RobAu No clue. My best guess is that they wanted to make simple clients (like command-line clients) not have to understand how to deal with relative URLs.